AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output: aapt2 W 04-22 13:22:29 43183 43183 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'
when i use  this dependencies
show erorr this
AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output:
aapt2 W 04-22 13:22:29 43183 43183 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'
dependencies {
  // ... other dependencies

  implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials:<latest version>"
  implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:<latest version>"
  implementation "com.google.android.libraries.identity.googleid:googleid:<latest version>"
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.base.hilt"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    kapt { generateStubs = true }
    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes = true
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/graphql'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
        viewBinding true
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

This is my buid gradle
I have change all possible
my distribuation url is
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
& gradle version 7.2
